# How to remove link tags from json data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, wordpress

I'm currently loading JSON data from a wordpress website, which looks like this:

```
"content": "<p>This is text which <a href="#">may have</a> some random links <a href="#">in</a> it.</p>",
```

**Controller**:

```
$http.get($scope.postUrl + $stateParams.postID + '?type[]=post')
    .success( function(data){
        $scope.post = data;
    })
    .error( function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
        $scope.errorMessage = "Item could not be found.";
    })
    .then( function() {
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-bind-html="post.content" class="post-content"></div>
```

I want to remove any links that may be in the original 'content', preferably with a filter. Has anyone else had a similar scenario and come up with a solution?

I tried in vain targeting them with a jquery selector:

```
$(document).ready(function () { $(".post-content a").contents().unwrap(); });
```

or at the controller level:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { $(".post-content a").contents().unwrap(); });
```

presumably these didn't work due to timing issues of the content not being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those attempts are close, but just short of what you want.

First, Angular's [element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) interface does not have the `unwrap` method. Ignore that if you're using jQuery, which you probably are. If you aren't, you want to pull jQuery in as a dependency before Angular.

Second, you can do your entire operation in the controller. Snipped:

```
$http.get($scope.postUrl + $stateParams.postID + '?type[]=post')
.success( function(data){
    var postContent = angular.element(data.content); // This wraps the HTML in jQuery
    postContent.find("a").contents().unwrap(); // Remove a tags
    $scope.post = $('<div>').append(postContent).html(); // Cast to HTML String
})
```

Comment: Using your code now successfully removes the links, however in the view `<div ng-bind-html="post"></div>` returns an [object Object] which on inspection is the parts of the html content i.e. `[p,text,p,text,p,text,p]`, is there a way to flatten it back to a string for outputting?

Comment: Right... you're getting the Angular element cast to string, which is a problem. You'll need to get the HTML string back out. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Perfect - that's done the trick. I've altered .unwrap() to be .contents().unwrap() as it was removing the whole containing paragraph before.

Comment: Added that bit. Not sure why your edit was rejected by other reviewers, I'd have approved it in a heartbeat.